# Why is there a nongreedy version of {m} in PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

On page 107 of the book Programming PHP by Kevin Tatroe and Peter MacIntyre, 3rd edition, it is stated that in PHP regular expressions, there is a nongreedy version `{m}?` of the quantifier `{m}`. The latter quantifier means "exactly m times" and I am wondering how this can be greedy or nongreedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A limiting quantifier can be both greedy and lazy (reluctant). The difference is only visible when you use both minimum and maximum values, e.g. `{1,5}` and `{1,5}?`.

When you use just the minimum threshold value, greedy and lazy versions yield the same behavior.

It seems that the `{m}?` is just there to keep consistency (`{n}` and `{n,m}` are both forms of the same [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that can be lazy or greedy), but is really redundant.